# AWS CodeBuild – Build does not have internet connectivity. Please check subnet network configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am experimenting with CodeBuild but have reached a dead-end. My build always fails with the error message:

> Build does not have internet connectivity. Please check subnet network configuration.

I checked the VPC configuration (subnet, security groups), and they seem okay. To test internet connectivity, I launched an EC2 instance in the same subnet, and it is able to communicate with external services (I tried a ping and some HTTP GETs).

How do I resolve this 'internet connectivity' issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you are assigning the CodeBuild project to a subnet, it must be a **private** subnet with a NAT gateway that is connected to the internet gateway.

I had this same issue, but I was quite early in the project so I could tear it down and start again.

From the [VPC Dashboard](http://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home) I used the  'Start VPC Wizard' button where I could select a template named 'VPC with Public and Private Subnets'. I still had to create the security groups and assign an elastic IP.

Once the new VPC was generated and configured I reconfigured my CodeBuild project to use the **private subnet** in the new VPC and the provisioning step succeeded.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I can't believe I overlooked this. When I read the first line of your answer I was in "slap your forehead John" mode.

Comment: I just lost a couple of hours for this. Future readers, do not ignore the bolded word **private**. It is important and makes a difference.

Answer (score 16):

CodeBuild builds require a NAT Gateway to reach the internet, because they do not get assigned a public IP address like an EC2 instance does in a public subnet.  You can think of it like CodeBuild builds are always in a private subnet in your VPC:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

See this documentation for more troubleshooting steps, including a CloudFormation template for setting up a VPC with a NAT Gateway:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html#troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks Clare. I've setup the NAT, and it has an Elastic IP and is on the same public subnet I had the EC2 instance on. I thought that was all the configuration needed. It doesn't seem to be the case. I've gone through the steps of the troubleshooting section already, and nothing obvious has seemed off. I need to further educate myself it seems.

Comment: Clare, I was missing the `private` part of the answer in when reading your answer. Thanks for your help.